# PowerShell Help (basic for loop)

Tags: powershell

Below is my PowerShell script:

```
$name  = 'name'
$name1 = 'tom'
$name2 = 'hari'

for ($i=0; $i -le 10; $i++) {
    $oname = "$name$i" 
    Write-Host  mynameis "$oname"
}
```

And the output is as below:

> my oname is name0
>   my oname is name1
>   my oname is name2
>   my oname is name3
>   my oname is name4
>   my oname is name5
>   my oname is name6
>   my oname is name7
>   my oname is name8
>   my oname is name9
>   my oname is name10

Now the question is: how can I get the value of the variables (`$name1 = 'tom'`, `$name2 = 'hari'`) in output line (my oname is name1 my oname is name2) ?

To make it clear screenshot of script and output below.

[image: output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the proper data structure for your data, in this case an array. Do not emulate arrays by using numbered distinct variables.

```
$names = 'tom', 'hari'

for ($i=0; $i -lt $names.Count; $i++) {
    $oname = $names[$i]
    Write-Host "my name is $oname"
}
```

or even simpler

```
$names = 'tom', 'hari'

$names | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "my name is $_"
}
```

Comment: Hi Ansgar, that make sense. Thank you